# Spawn separate process from jboss

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I need to invoke a shell script as a separate process from a web application hosted on jboss. I am using the following code to invoke the process:

```
ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("file.sh");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
File file = new File(directory);
builder.directory(file);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.start();
```

The problem is that when i kill/stop the jboss the execution of the script also stops.The execution environment is linux.

Comment: Good question. Have you tried calling `/bin/bash file.sh` in the background? I think it might survive your Java process.

Comment: I have invoked the shell file in the background as well but it does not work. The reason seems to be that the shell script is being invoked as a sub process of the jboss. Stopping/Killing the jboss process also kills this process. So is there a way to invoke a process that is not a child process of jboss ?